# Как мне транспонировать (перевернуть) матрицу?

Tags: python, математика, numpy, матрицы

Как получить с этого:

```
import numpy as np

B = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
```

вот это:

```
A = np.matrix([[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]])
```

используя numpy?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Примите ответ, а то он так и всплывает в ленте как будто не отвеченный

Answer (score 5):

Воспользуйтесь [атрибутом `.T` (возвращает транспонированный результат)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html):

```
res = B.T
```

или функцией [np.transpose()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html):

```
res = np.transpose(B)
```